# What is the right way to put the value for the 'limit' property of the Paginator in CakePHP into a config file

Tags: cakephp

Using CakePHP 1.3 I created a small application which has a FooController. In this FooController I am using the Paginator to deliver the content of Foo to its views.

In the head of the FooController class I customized the preparation of the data from Foo like this:

```
var $paginate = array(
  'limit' => 100,
  'order' => array('Order.created' => 'desc'));
```

Now I would like to put the value for 'limit' into a configuration file.

So I created a file `$config['list_length'] = '500';` in the config directory which I load in bootstrap.php. That works fine, I can echo the value of `list_length`, for example in the `beforeFilter()` of the class.

But I fail to make the Paginator use that value.

First I tried:

```
var $paginate = array(
  'limit' => Configure::read('list_length'),
  'order' => array('Order.created' => 'desc'));
```

But that fails with the following PHP error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in xyz/app/controllers/foo_controller.php on line 9
```

Then I tried:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  parent::beforeFilter();

  $paginate['limit'] = Configure::read('list_length');
}
```

But it would still use the value '100' instead of '500'.

I guess this is a rather trivial problem that really comes from the fact that I am not very proficient with basic PHP concepts. I don't have much opportunity to get to program a little bit in my current job, so I'm really out of practice.

I would very much appreciate any hint on how to do this and even more on what concept I am missing here, so I could read a little bit about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *almost* got it right;

The reason PHP is giving you the error in your first example is that class properties cannot be set using 'dynamic' values; from the documentation:

*This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, **it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.***

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

If you need to set a property to a value that is 'dynamic' (e.g. The result of a function), you will need to assign if from within a class 'method'

You tried to do this in your second example, however, properties of a class/object should be accessed using `$this->nameOfTheProperty` to indicate it is not a 'variable', but a **'property'** of the object;

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->paginate['limit'] = Configure::read('list_length');
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This helps big time! It works perfectly now and I (re-)learned something. Thanks a million!

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your project!